# In Linear Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

**I did not found the result  which using with method(seperable,homogeneous,first Ordered,exact  like  that.)**

**$\left( 5x+3e^{y}\right) dx+2xe^{y}dy=0$**

Comment: It isn't exact, so you'd need to find an integrating factor (unless there is perhaps some typo)

Answer (score 1):

$$\left( 5x+3e^{y}\right) dx+2xe^{y}dy=0$$
$$\left( 5x+3e^{y}\right) +2xe^{y}\frac {dy} {dx}=0$$
We have that $y'= \frac {dy}{dx}$:
$$2xe^{y}y'+\left( 5x+3e^{y}\right) =0$$

Since $(e^y)'=e^yy'$
$$ 2x(e^{y})'+5x+3e^{y}=0$$
It's a simple first order linear equation

Substitute $z=e^y$ and solve.
$$ 2xz'+3z=-5x$$

Comment: as  if you  dont it or  ı didn t get  it

Comment: Do you know how to solve a first order linear eqaution ? @aaronswartz

Comment: partially, but  you  dont  use  exponantial expression.You wish  write  all statements.

Comment: @aaronswartz can you solve the last equation I wrote in z ?

Comment: Sure.It easier  part  of question

Comment: Substitute back then $z=e^y$

Comment: absolutely,I'd review derivative of e^y

Comment: @aaronswartz well the derivative of $e^y$ is $e^yy'$ and derivative of $e^x$ is $e^x$  when you take the derivative with respect to $x$

Comment: Thanks  Sir ,I understood   right now  according to  y take  derivative so  $e^{y}y^{'}$

Comment: @aaronswartz Thats great !!

Comment: I hope did not steal  your  time. I feel like  idiot  myself.

Comment: @aaronswartz there are no idiot question. All the questions are good to be asked.

Comment: Appriciate  for  every contributes.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it: try to find an integrating factor $\mu(x,y)$. This will satisfy

$$5x\mu_y + 3e^y \mu + 3e^y \mu_y = 2 e^y \mu + 2x e^y \mu_x.$$

A common situation is that $\mu$ depend only on one variable. If we guess that $\mu$ depends only on $x$ then the equation reduces to $e^y \mu = 2xe^y \mu_x$ or $\mu=2x\mu'$, which is indeed an ODE only in terms of $x$, so we can proceed this way. One solution to this ODE is $\mu=x^{1/2}$. This reduces the original ODE to

$$(5x^{3/2} + 3x^{1/2} e^y) dx + 2x^{3/2} e^y dy = 0$$

which is now exact, so you can write the solution implicitly in terms of $f(x,y)=C$ where $f$ is an associated potential function, and then in this particular case you can solve that equation explicitly for $y$.

What about $x<0$? To generalize you can take $\mu=|x|^{1/2}$, which will have the desired behavior for $x<0$.